# Laptop Screen does not turn on after sleep

Tags: 10.10, laptop, suspend-resume

I recently put Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop and after fixing the wireless problem I am only stuck on my screen turning back on after sleep. I have had this problem since Ubuntu 7. I tried using Ubuntu way back then and had a whole bunch of issues with the sleep and the wireless(Broadcom 4311). Anyways, I have an ATI Radeon express 200M graphics card (old laptop). When I go to Hardware drivers it doesn't give me any options to use the closed source drivers. Any suggestions on what I should do?

I am going to try what is suggested in this thread but I am at work right now.
[Laptop does not wake up after sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14289/laptop-does-not-wake-up-after-sleep)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please first try the suggestions in that question, then if the accepted answers do not work for you - open a new question. Creating possible duplicates will not create an answer any sooner.

Comment: I asking this because I don't think selecting Blank screen when closing my laptop is an acceptable solution. I need the computer to turn off not keep running. I heard somewhere this could be a graphics card issue and was hoping someone else with ATI was having this problem and found a solution.

Comment: Hi! Did it work for you?

Comment: have you tried putting the laptop sleep mode using the function key to sleep mode before closing the lid

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3):

I too have this problem on my laptop. I dont know the solution but I found a workaround for this. Laptops have a hardware key or a key combination (generally Fn key + some function key) to switch between displays. When my laptop wakes and I get the blank screen, I press that key combination and I get my display back. I think what happens is that the OS tries to connect to external display but when it cant find one it reverts back to laptops LCD which does the magic and turns it on. You can try this and tell us if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I would close screen and computer would go to sleep. when I would open screen the computer powered up, lights on keyboard came on, but screen would not fire up. I would then have to do hard reset. I have ati graphics card also. I tried all the fixes and workarounds that were suggested which didn't work. finally fixed the problem by swapping out my ram. changed out both sticks of ram- problem solved!!

Comment: I have the same problem. How do you swapping your ram? Can you be more specific? I am Ubuntu beginner. Thanks.