# Screen stays black after Waking Up from Suspend

Tags: 12.04, power-management, suspend, wakeup

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on HP DM4 Beats Edition and the suspend and wake up were working perfectly, but after an update I can't see 'Caps Lock' light, Wireless light etc, the fan is running but the screen stays black.
Anyone else has spotted this? Is this a bug? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/19111/laptop-screen-does-not-turn-on-after-sleep

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/14289/laptop-does-not-wake-up-after-sleep

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I am having the same issue, my solution is to after wakeup, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, then Ctrl+Alt+F7, and my desktop shows up.